# Error NullPointerException al enviar dato booleano a otra activity Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-intent

Tengo una activity que debe enviar un boolean a otra activity al pulsar un botón para realizar una acción u otra. Este dato se envía sí o sí. En la primera activity solo tengo este código:

```
    miButtonSettings.setOnClickListener {
        val i = Intent(applicationContext, SettingsActivity::class.java)
        i.putExtra("cambio", false)
        startActivity(i)
    }
```

En la segunda activity simplemente hago esto. El error se produce en la segunda línea de este código:

```
    val i = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
    cambioActivity = i.extras!!.getBoolean("cambio")
```

Este es el error completo que me da:

```
    Process: com.example.sqlite, PID: 2624
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sqlite/com.example.sqlite.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.sqlite.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.kt:36)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731
```

Gracias.

Comment: No definas en SettingsActivity un nuevo Intent para obtener el valor, esto puede causar NullPointerException, agregué respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener el valor en el método onCreate de la segunda actividad utiliza el la propiedad de la actividad

> getIntent()//en java
> intent.extras!!.getBoolean("cambio") // en kotlin

en lugar de

> val i = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)

Comment: Cierto, así sí funciona Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Revisa la clase `SettingsActivity.kt`, primeramente es super importante recibas el valor en el método `onCreate()`, de otra forma obtendrás valores null.

Ahora no necesitas definir un `Intent` ya que esto también puede provocar un `NullPointerException`, simplemente obtén el valor de esta forma.

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        ...
        ...

        cambioActivity = intent.extras!!.getBoolean("cambio")
            

    }
```

Comment: Gracias, así me funciona.